# SpringBoot JPA need no .save() on @Transactional?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have short question:

Do I need a `repo.save(x)` call on `@Transactional` methods?

I ask cause I see changes on my DB without save, and read no clear docs about it.

So is it working as intended, or just a (welcome) unexpected behavior?

example:

```
@Autowired
private UserRepo repo;

@Transactional  
@PutMapping
public Long put(@RequestBody User user)
{
  User u = repo.findOne(user.getId());
  u.setName("Paul");
  repo.save(u); // DO I NEED THIS LINE?
}
```

I'am just unsure about it, so maybe someone can shed some light on the subject?

Comment: yes, this is normal in managed (JEE / JTA) eninvronment. Every attached object is saved

Comment: @YannicKlem persisted entities are saved by Hibernate when a transaction is flushed, so no manual `save()` is necessary. This is described in [11.5 Modifying persistent objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-modifying). No clue if this is a feature solely within Hibernate, or if this is described within the JPA specification as well.

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I was completely unaware of this behavior!

Comment: Thank you :) That clears it

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you retrieve an entity, for example using the `findOne` method call within a transactional method it has become **managed** from that point by the persistence provider.

Now if you make any changes to that entity (which is actually a proxy object), upon transaction commit, those changes will be persisted to the database, regardless of the fact of invoking the `save` or `update` methods.

`save` or `persist` has to be used when you are creating a new entity from scratch and persistence provider does not know of its existence yet.

Remember that you can prevent making any changes upon commit, if you use `detach` or `evict` methods on that particular entity before those changes occur.

Comment: Thank you, sounds good for me.

Comment: hi if i use findById, setValue(changeSomeValue) and then do save(oldObject) and then i going to delete(oldObject), but the result my save(oldObject) is not executed, the jpa only execute delete(oldObject) in the last action, but if i comment the delete line, the code is updating, can u help me? here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64331680/how-to-force-transactional-in-jpa-to-commit-two-repository-action-not-only-just/64399901#64399901